# Django load wrong template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django. I am trying to configure an app called 'faq', and an index page to display the different "apps", including the previous one.

I was following the [Learn Django site guide](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/template-structure) to decide what was best for the template structure.

1. So, I configured `myproject/settings.py` to let load the template from `templates` folder: `'DIRS': ['templates'],`.
2. In the app folder `myproject/apps/faq` I have created a `templates` folder.
3. In the app views `myproject/apps/faq/views.py` I defined the views to load the data from database and send it back to the template:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def faqs_view(request):
    faqs = FrequentAskedQuestion.objects.all()
    context = { 'faqs': faqs }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def faq_view(request, id):
    faq = FrequentAskedQuestion.objects.get(id=id)
    print(faq)
    context = { 'faq': faq }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

4. In the app folder I have created a URLconf configuration in `myproject/apps/faq/urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import faqs_view, faq_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', faqs_view, name='faq-list'),
    path('<int:id>', faq_view, name='faq-detail'),
]
```

> A parenthesis here, since the first attempt I have tried to create a project `templates` folder and use the project `views.py` and `urls.py`and it didn't work I decided to create another app called `main`.

5. In the app folder `myproject/apps/main` I have created a `templates` folder.
6. In the app views `myproject/apps/main/views.py` I defined just a simple view to render the app list:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index_view(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

7. In the app folder I have created also a `urls.py` and added the previous view:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import index_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index_view, name='site-index'),
]
```

8. In the project URLconf file I have added both apps:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myproject.apps.main.urls'), name='site-index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin-index'),
    path('faq/', include('myproject.apps.faq.urls'), name='faq-index'),
]
```

After the previous setup I got working 'faq' app and it works great. But, whenever I go to `http://localhost:8000/` it display the title from `myproject/apps/faq/templates/index` when it should display `myproject/apps/main/templates/index`.

Maybe it is worth to mention that both templates (`main/templates/index` and `faq/templates/index`) inherit from a base template that is created in each app template folder.

#### The file tree:

- myproject

  - apps

    - faq

      - templates

        - base.html
        - index.html
      - urls.py
      - views.py
    - main

      - templates

        - base.html
        - index.html
      - urls.py
      - views.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py

I am doing something wrong. So, any clues?

Comment: Can you please define a filetree. Typically under the `templates` directory, one writes the app name, so `myproject/apps/faq/templates/faq/index.html`, such that you refer to it with `render(request, 'faq/index.html')` to avoid "name clashes").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you write the name of the app under the `templates` directory, so:

```
faq/
  templates/
    faq/
      index.html
```

This creates a sort of "namespace", such that you can reference to the correct file with:

from django.shortcuts import render

```
def index_view(request):
    return render(request, 'faq/index.html')
```

If you do not construct such directory, then Djangno will simply search for a file named `index.html` in *all* the template directories. So if there are multiple, it depends on the order in which the template directories are searched.

Comment: Using that file tree it didn't work since it couldn't find the template in the `myproject/templates` directory. So, what worked for me thanks to you was creating a project `templates` directory and subdirectories like `templates/main` and `templates/faq`.

Comment: @MartínFernández: did you enable the [**`APP_DIRS`** setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-APP_DIRS)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But no matter whether I change the `DIRS` setting it search for the project template directory. But is fine to me, I will try this in a future project. Thank you.