# Tried to create three apps in Django but when try to click on third app it routes to the second app page settings templates DIR allows routing 2 DIRs

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings, django-apps

in this below code i explained How i rooted the templated but only first two roots are working when click on my third app it automatically rooted to my second app

```
#--assigning apps templates as values--    
mail = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'mail/templates')
    cloud = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'cloud_storage/templates')
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            #--rooting the values as dirs --
            'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'Home/templates',cloud,mail,],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Firstly you don't need to add those directories to the template directories list assuming that `cloud_storage` and `mail` are the name of your apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django load wrong template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955884/django-load-wrong-template)